# My virtual machine cannot connect to a database on the host

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

Dear friends / colleagues:
I have VMware Workstation Pro 15.5 installed on my physical machine, which has Windows 10.

I also have an Informix database engine running correctly on this machine. In addition, I have the programs of a commercial application for other machines to run.

Now, in Workstation I have created a virtual machine with Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit.

When I want to access the database from the virtual machine, I get an error telling me that the connection could not be established and throws me an Informix -908 error. This error says the following:
"**-908 Attempt to connect to database server (servername) failed."

The program or application is trying to access another database server but has failed. Note the server name in the current statement.
The desired database server is unavailable, or the network is down or is congested. Ask your DBA and system administrator to verify that the server and network are operational. If the network is congested, use the environment variables INFORMIXCONTIME and INFORMIXCONRETRY to tune connection timing. For information on setting these environment variables, see the IBM Informix Guide to SQL: Reference.
This message appears in Version 6.0 and later versions.**

I tell you something important: 10 days ago I had Workstation Pro 14 installed, with the same virtual machine, and it connected perfectly to the database. I had to update to version 15.5 since after a Windows 10 update the VM stopped working correctly (it didn't delete the .lck files). With this new version this does not happen, but it does not connect to the database.

At first I blamed Bitdefender 2020 for this failure, but I uninstalled it, and it continues to occur.

Now it seems to me that it is more a generic configuration flaw, but I don't know how to correct it. What catches my attention is that 3 IP addresses appear on my desk: that of my physical machine, and two more that I suppose are those of the Workstation.

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Of course, I appreciate your attention.

Comment: You should be able to look at the network settings on the VM to see what IP address it has. It's unlikely it has both of the IPs you don't recognize

Comment: What networking option are you using?  Sounds like NAT, if you've got 3 IPs.  You probably want to set up bridged and use that for the best compatibility as it essentially puts your VM on the network the same as the host.